# How to see the stack trace of a deployed application that crashes on run

Tags: c#, initialization

I have an application that crashes as soon as it is launched but only after deployment (it will run fine in debug mode).

For simplicity I've been deploying it as a CD style deployment in visual studio 2012.

This is a c# windows application.

The errors thrown (in the event log) are as follows:

```
Application: applaunch.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at Konformance.App.Main()
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.String[])
   at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly, System.String[])
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean)
   at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.NewThreadRunner()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,             System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Followed by:

```
Faulting application name: applaunch.exe, version: 4.0.30319.33440, time stamp: 0x52003c5a
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504ade
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00014598
Faulting process ID: 0x1a64
Faulting application start time: 0x01d02c18ff5c4f43
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\applaunch.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report ID: 3ee36614-980c-11e4-8354-b8ca3a87a278
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

What would be the most likely cause of this?

Thanks

Comment: console? wpf? winforms? asp? can you show any initialization code?

Comment: Hi Default, I added that it's a c# windows app. What would you be looking for in the initialization code? I don't want to dump the whole file here. Thanks

Comment: anything really, this is a mere guessing game at the moment. Can you try and catch unhandled exceptions via `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += OnThreadException;` and check the inner exception? That might pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Thanks Default - Stumbled on the cause and it was something totally unrelated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be caused by a problem with a user making a mistake with the versioning software (SVN). The result was several sections were removed from the .proj file resulting in the deployed package not being configured correctly.